# include não funciona

Tags: php, html, include

fiz um sistema modular no qual cada parte das paginas ficam em uma pasta, o problema é que tenho uma pagina com um formulário que está dentro de uma modal, esse formulário recebe informações do banco, quando eu rodo só o formulário ele funciona corretamente e quando eu rodo a pagina da modal ela também funciona, mas quando eu rodo a pagina inteira com recebo o erro no include

> Warning: include(../form/formCriar.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\CRUD\modal\modalCriar.php on line 11.

Estrutura de paginas

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pagina na qual o erro é gerado

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="criar" class="modal modal-fixed-footer">
    <div class="modal-content" style="overflow-x: hidden;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12">
                <h4></h4>
                <p class="grey-text">

                </p>
            </div>
            <?php  include("../form/formCriar.php");  ?>
            <p class="Falha red-text center"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#!" class="modal-close btn-flat">Cancelar</a>
        <button class="btn cyan" type="submit" form="formCriar">Criar</button>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Fim Modal-->
```

Comment: O problema provavelmente está no fato de você usar o caminho relativo, tente `include dirname(__FILE__)."../form/formCriar.php";`

Comment: Tentei isso e infelizmente não deu certo :/